# php not recognizing string when passing to a js parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, parameters

I am currently working on a webiste and I am using php to connect to the database.
I have a section where I want to have a html `<button>` tag that changes the src of the same `<img>` tag. so, i used javascript to make this (this was also from stackoverflow...)

```
    function changeImage(x)
    {
    var img = document.getElementById("change_image");
    img.src=x;

    }
    </script>
```

i want to have the parameter `x`, which is the name of the img (the src part. e.g. flower.jpg). inside the php code, i have a line
`echo '<button class="button_a" onclick="changeImage(',$row['photo_a'],');"></button>';`

**$row['photo_a'] is the file flower.jpg**

which is a code to create the button and call the function `changeImage`

this only gives me the error
`ReferenceError: flower is not defined`

i believe that this is becuase this is not noticeded as a string, but how can i fix this?

Comment: You have to put the php variable $row variable between quotes - now they are treated as a js variable with the name flower, not as text: echo ```'<button class="button_a" onclick="changeImage(\''.$row['photo_a'].'\');"></button>'```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011650/place-a-onclick-inside-a-php-echo